# How to transform mysql query into Yii CDbCriteria object?

Tags: yii

I have a model `Reporter`.

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'video' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Video', 'reporter_id'),
    );
}
```

I have a mysql query for `Reporter->search()` method:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(t1.id) AS 'reports'
FROM reporter AS t
LEFT JOIN video AS t1 ON t.id = t1.reporter_id  
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.name
```

How can it be written in terms of `CDbCriteria` to use with `CActiveDataProvider`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write that query into the criteria for a CActiveDataProvider you'll need to set the following properties from CDbCriteria:

[select](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#select-detail),
[join](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#join-detail),
[group](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#group-detail), and 
[order](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#order-detail).

You can then set them while creating a new CActiveDataProvider object like so:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Reporter', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'select'=>'`t`.*, count(`t1`.`id`) as `reports`',
        'join'=>'LEFT JOIN `video` AS `t1` ON `t`.`id` = `t1`.`reporter_id`',
        'group'=>'`t`.`id`',
        'order'=>'`t`.`name`',
    ),
));
```

The whole list of properties and methods that you can use with CDbCriteria can be found here: [CDbCriteria Class Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria)